# LaTeX equation not numbered correctly with cases

Tags: equations, numbering, cases

I'm trying to write a simple case equation with the following code:

```
\begin{align}
\begin{equation}
  S_{new}=
  \begin{cases}
    max(S_{new}) &\text{if $S_{CTA} > 70 \parallel S_{DCE-CT} < \tau_{flow}$}\\
    0.2\log({S_{CTA}/80}) + 0.8\log({\tau_{flow}/S_{DCE-CT}}) &\text{else}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{align}
```

Which outputs this [image: incorrect number]

The equation number should be (1) not (2), how do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ....

Comment: You cannot nest `equation` within `align`; remove the outer `align` environment. You should be getting errors from that code. *Never* ignore TeX errors; the resulting output is in general garbage, as in this case.

Comment: It's almost certainly because of the `align` outside the `equation`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I add two possibilities. The second is the best because the `geometry` package provides uniformity for the sheet margins. In addition I have tried to improve some code anomalies as highlighted in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  S_{\textup{new}}=
  \begin{cases}
    \max(S_{\textup{new}}) \quad \text{if $S_{CTA} > 70 \parallel S_{DCE-CT} < \tau_{\textup{flow}}$}\\
    0.2\log({S_{CTA}/80}) + 0.8\log({\tau_{\textup{flow}}/S_{DCE-CT}}) &\text{else}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  S_{\textup{new}}=
  \begin{cases}
    \max(S_{\textup{new}}) & \text{if $S_{CTA} > 70 \parallel S_{DCE-CT} < \tau_{\textup{flow}}$}\\
    0.2\log({S_{CTA}/80}) + 0.8\log({\tau_{\textup{flow}}/S_{DCE-CT}}) &\text{else}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### An addendum after the comment of @Zarko using `\usepackage{cases}` with the enviroment `numcases`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}

\begin{numcases} 
  {S_{\textup{new}}=}
    \max(S_{\textup{new}}) & \text{if $S_{CTA} > 70 \parallel S_{DCE-CT} < \tau_{\text{flow}}$}\\
    0.2\log({S_{CTA}/80}) + 0.8\log({\tau_{\textup{flow}}/S_{DCE-CT}}) &\text{else}
    \end{numcases} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I correctly understand OP,  (s)he like to have numbered each equation in cases (as is for example provided by `numcases` environment defined in the `cases` package package.

Comment: @Zarko You know that I not understand well the English language. :-) With a lot of sincerity I have not understood that the user want numbered every equation. :-(

Comment: Oh, I may be wrong. Code fragment is erroneous and question is unclear. It seems that both have fogy crystal balls :-). I'm sure that your English is slightly better than mine ;-). Anyway, I give +1 :-)

Comment: @Zarko Yes yes. You always compliment me and still after 5 years I sometimes use the translator LOL :-)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. As some commenters mentioned, the {align} outside of {equation} was the issue. I accepted Sebastiano's answer since it both solves the issue but also looks better than what I originally wanted (Thanks lol).

Comment: Again, `\text` should never be used  for upright text in subscripts (or similar), `\text` does not do what you think. Please use `\mathrm` or even `\textup` in those subscripts instead.

Comment: @agw3333 I am very happy to help you...You're welcome.

Comment: @daleif You're right, sometimes I forgot this. I now improve the code.